# Dynamically added methods for extensions, Groovy/Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

When I add an extension to a Gradle project [the Gradle docs say](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/plugins/ExtensionContainer.html):

```
Adding an extension of name 'foo' will:
add 'foo' dynamic property
add 'foo' dynamic method that accepts a closure that is a configuration script block
```

Is there any way I can configure the dynamic method that accepts a closure, or even better replace it with a method I write by hand? I want to add custom preprocessing logic.

Comment: I can see you want to add an extension but what are you trying to achieve? can you explain a bit what you are doing?

Comment: The extension stores some global configuration information that I use in my build. After I process the `foo {...}` closure in my `build.gradle` file I want to do some extra bookkeeping that the automatically generated `foo` method doesn't do.